# Check whether url returns 404

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to check whether an URL returns 404, 403 etc when including a Javascript file. It works ok, but I still get an error in "Chrome developer tools".

This is my code:

```
(function() { 
try
  {
            var ml = document.createElement('script'); 
        ml.type = 'text/javascript';    
        ml.async = true; 
        ml.id = 'monoloop_invoke'; 
        ml.onerror = function(){alert('File does not exist');};
        ml.src = 'http://somedomain.com/somefile.js';
            var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
            s.parentNode.insertBefore(ml, s);

  }
catch(err)
  {
    alert('Error: '+err);
  }
        })
    ();
```

If the file does not exist it shows the error "File does not exist" from the `ml.onerror` function. This is all good. But the problem is that I still get an error line in my console like:

```
GET http://somedomain.com/somefile.js 403 (Forbidden)
```

and the try/catch does not catch this error.

Anyone knows how to solve this? Or is there another way of testing if a URL exists before including it? I cannot use AJAX as I need to use this in a cross-domain fashion. I could use jQuery if necessary.

EDIT: It does not show an error in IE, so i guess this maybe just relates to the way chrome reports issues. Does anyone see a more elegant solution for checking if a file exisists without genreting anything in the console.

Comment: Well, you made the request, so of course Chrome is going to show you that it returned a 403.

Comment: I don't think that will generate an error.

Can't you use Ajax and call that page, get the content and interpret it?

Comment: Inserting `script` tags to the DOM with a `src` attribute that refers to an invalid URL... throws an exception, now?

Comment: @Jeremy - I understand it will show this info in Network if i look there, but i need it to not show in console (error console)

Comment: @Tomalak - Well, it does not throw an exception, i guess, since its not catched by the try/catch, but for some reason its still shown as an error in chromes console...

Comment: @sunebrodersen: Transfer errors in your browser and Javascript exceptions are completely unrelated. This approach will not work.

Comment: @Tomalak - so its not possible to avoid the loading error in chrome i guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
jQuery.getScript( url, [ success(data, textStatus) ] )
```

> Description: Load a JavaScript file from the server using a GET HTTP request, then execute it.
>
> url
>       A string containing the URL to which the request is sent.
>
> success(data, textStatus)
>       A callback function that is executed if the request succeeds.

To catch the errors use the ajaxError event:

http://api.jquery.com/ajaxError/

Comment: From the question: "I cannot use AJAX as I need to use this in a cross-domain fashion." Of course, this requirement probably makes the entire gambit impossible... but still.

Comment: This seems to work just fine - also crossdomain - in all browsers, but it still generates "GET http://somedomain.com/somefile.js 403 (Forbidden)" in the chrome console - but maybe thats just something thats not possible to change