# Javascript error in FF

Tags: javascript

I am trying to execute a javascript and there is this error thrown:

```
Timestamp: 10/25/2012 2:23:13 PM
Error: SyntaxError: syntax error
Source File: http://www.facebook.com/dia.makoetskiy
Line: 1
Source Code:
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

It points to this line.. althought it is not line 1 in the document.

```
<script src="http://www.facebook.com/dia.makoetskiy" onload="logged()" onerror="notlogged()"></script>
```

Whats the problem with firefox?

Chrome says that I have a syntax error:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Why is it an error..? why the hole page crashes on firefox but it is okay on chrome/

I think the error of the first line is from facebook..  but how do I prevent this? it retrieves the document from that page, and that document ruins the javascript external link syntax

Answer (score 3):

`http://www.facebook.com/dia.makoetskiy` is an HTML document, not a JavaScript program.

`<!DOCTYPE html>` is line one of that resource, not the document containing the `<script>` element.

Comment: true.. I noticed it now.. but how can prehaps suppress error throwing on firefox? chrome doesnt throw an error

Comment: @DmitryMakovetskiyd What is it exactly that you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: try to find out if the page retrieves error 404 or not and based on that trigger an error event

Comment: Maybe this will be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5992631/check-whether-url-returns-404 Note that it may not be possible due to cross domain scripting restrictions.

Comment: lol..but that is the whole point.. working around the cross domain issue.. is there a way to suppress the firefox error?

Answer (score 0):

Facebook does not return a 404 response for non existent pages like  `http://www.facebook.com/some-super-bogus-username`

http://redbot.org/?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fsome-super-bogus-username

It simply reports back `HTTP/1.1 302 Found`

And besides doing such a check with javascript is not ideal. [Easy way to test a URL for 404 in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/408405/easy-way-to-test-a-url-for-404-in-php)